# Python3 's try/except not working when using requests library

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote a simple program using `requests` library, I want to print *'sorry, the url does not exist!'* if input url is wrong. I found that if I input a fake url to 
`get_request()` function, it will give me a `ConnectionError` error, thus I put it after `except`:

```
import requests

def get_request(url):
    a = requests.get(url)
    return a

myurl = 'https://nberccc.com/videos?page=1' # a fake website url
try:
    c = get_request(myurl)   
except ConnectionError:
    print('sorry, the url does not exist!')
```

it returns:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
gaierror                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py in _new_conn(self)
    158             conn = connection.create_connection(
--> 159                 (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
    160 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, socket_options)
     56 
---> 57     for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
     58         af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py in getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags)
    747     addrlist = []
--> 748     for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
    749         af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res

gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NewConnectionError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    599                                                   body=body, headers=headers,
--> 600                                                   chunked=chunked)
    601 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    342         try:
--> 343             self._validate_conn(conn)
    344         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError) as e:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _validate_conn(self, conn)
    838         if not getattr(conn, 'sock', None):  # AppEngine might not have  `.sock`
--> 839             conn.connect()
    840 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py in connect(self)
    300         # Add certificate verification
--> 301         conn = self._new_conn()
    302         hostname = self.host

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py in _new_conn(self)
    167             raise NewConnectionError(
--> 168                 self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
    169 

NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001602C18F4E0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

MaxRetryError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    448                     retries=self.max_retries,
--> 449                     timeout=timeout
    450                 )

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    637             retries = retries.increment(method, url, error=e, _pool=self,
--> 638                                         _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
    639             retries.sleep()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py in increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    397         if new_retry.is_exhausted():
--> 398             raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
    399 

MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='porndoe111.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /videos?page=1 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001602C18F4E0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-f61b8d93ce3e> in <module>
      1 myurl = 'https://nberccc.com/videos?page=1'
----> 2 requests.get(url)
      3 
      4 def get_request(url):
      5     a = requests.get(url)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py in get(url, params, **kwargs)
     73 
     74     kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
---> 75     return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
     76 
     77 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     58     # cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
     59     with sessions.Session() as session:
---> 60         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
     61 
     62 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    531         }
    532         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 533         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    534 
    535         return resp

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    644 
    645         # Send the request
--> 646         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    647 
    648         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    514                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    515 
--> 516             raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
    517 
    518         except ClosedPoolError as e:

ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='porndoe111.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /videos?page=1 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001602C18F4E0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))
```

Why it doesn't print my own error message?

when I run this:

```
myurl1 = 'https://github.com/songxxiao' # a normal website url
try:
    c = get_request(myurl1)   
except ConnectionError:
    print('sorry, the url does not exist!')
```

it works well.

So how to modify my code above to catch that Error and print my own error message?

Comment: tried with `except Exception` ? for a more generalized exception

Comment: Try catching exception in super class first, for example instead of `ConnectionError`, do `Exception`. It's possible that the exception type it's throwing on website not found is actually of some other type

Comment: @mrid @saadi  use `except Exception` seems still not working. or may I code incorrectly ?

Comment: You need to catch OSError.

Comment: @Xiao Song the code works fine when using `except Exception`, do you get the same error when using `except Exception` ??

Comment: @MattShin Thanks! Catching OSError works well, how do you figure out that?

Comment: Had a similar problem before. Haha

Comment: @MattShin Thank you again! But I still don't know why catching OSError is a solution for this problem  :D

Comment: The error raised by the socket library to resolve the URL is actually a sub class of OSError.